# How to report unsuccessful commands on remote machines?

Tags: bash

For instance, I wrote a simple script to delete all the jar files on remote machines.

```
## distribute commands to machines
for machine in $machines
do
    echo $machine       
    ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $machine "rm /home/ubuntu/test.jar" &
done
```

I want to know whether all these commands were successful. Is there any convenient way?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `&` backgrounding the `ssh`es and then you can check their exit status with `if` or `||`.

```
for machine in $machines; do
    echo $machine       
    if ! ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $machine rm /home/ubuntu/test.jar; then
        echo "didn't work" >&2
    fi
done
```

or

```
succeeded=true

for machine in $machines; do
    echo $machine       
    ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $machine rm /home/ubuntu/test.jar || succeeded=false
done

if ! $succeeded; then
    echo "one or more removals failed" >&2
fi
```